# What does FlightCrew's "Unable to find zip structure: End-of-central-directory" mean?

Tags: epub, validation

I am experimenting with building my own `.epub` files and try to validate them using [FlightCrew](http://code.google.com/p/flightcrew/).

Currently it says my file is invalid because it is

> Unable to find zip structure: End-of-central-directory

What could this mean what could be the reason for such a message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would mean your EPUB does not have a proper ZIP file structure.

You can try listing the content of your file with a normal zip unpacker, or test it with a real epubreader. If those do not complain, it could mean that FlightCrew has a bug.

Comment: You are right, I used 7zip after FlightCrew complained about mimetype not being the first file within the `.epub`. This resulted in generating a `.7z` file, which is indeed no valid `.zip`.